# How to write contents of RDD onto S3?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I have an RDD containing vertex id and it's x,y coordinates, I want to write its contents to a text file, on my local machine I'm doing that using a function

```
  def printVertices(iterable: Iterable[Vertex], filename: String): Unit = {
    val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(filename))
    for (point <- iterable) {
      pw.write(point.id + ", " + point.coordinate.x + ", " + point.coordinate.y + "\n")
    }
    pw.close()
  }

printVertices(dt.points.collect, s"$output/points$id.txt")
```

In the above code dt.points is an RDD, I want to save it to a text file if I do RDD.saveAsTextFile it writes the whole RDD, so I want to use my method and write to s3.

Answer (score 0):

For writing RDD, as a text file, on S3, just add `s3a` to the URI. Like this:

```
printVertices(dt.points.collect, s"s3a://$bucketName/$output/points$id.txt")
```

Also, you have to include following JARs, if you are using Spark 2.2+

- `hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar`, and
- `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar`

Comment: I tried this it didn't work I get file not found error, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use seratch/AWScala library and the way to use it (by their docs) is

```
import awscala._, s3._
implicit val s3 = S3.at(Region.Tokyo)

val buckets: Seq[Bucket] = s3.buckets
val bucket: Bucket = s3.createBucket("unique-name-xxx")
val summaries: Seq[S3ObjectSummary] = bucket.objectSummaries

bucket.put("sample.txt", new java.io.File("sample.txt"))
```

so in your case, you need to get the bucket first

```
val bucket: Bucket = s3.bucket("your bucket unique name").get
```

and put the file in the bucket

```
bucket.put(s"$output/points$id.txt", new java.io.File("s"$output/points$id.txt""))
```